# how to dispaly 2 views using UI-router in a single state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('app', {
 url: "/app",
 cached:false,
 abstract: true,
 templateUrl: "views/menu.html",
 controller : 'AuthController'
})

.state('app.home', {
 url: "/home",
 templateUrl: "views/home.html",
 controller : 'DashBoardController',
})
```

The thing here is when i access the app.home via state.go() . I only see the menu.html, the home.html is not showing, and there is no error on my logs. How can i make the menu.html and home.html show ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

[You will have to use multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Sample Snippet :

Defining Routes :

```
.state('app', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        'menu@app': {
            templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',
            controller: 'MenuController'
        },
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        }
    },
    abstract: true
});

.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller : 'DashBoardController'
});
```

main.html :

```
<div ui-view="menu"></div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Comment: thank you for responding @Akshay Garg, i already did it by putting 

<div ui-view></div> inside the menu.html